# Heroku Error H13

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've been getting this error now on & off for the past couple days since I deployed my application to heroku. It happens both before I started using unicorn as a server as well as afterwards. I can sometimes get it back up and running by using `heroku run rake db:migrate` then `heroku restart` but this only fixes it for a couple hours and it's broken again. As for the webpage it's saying "Application error". The logs aren't very helpful but here's what it says each time this error happens:

```
[2014-10-27T21:13:31.675956 #2] ERROR -- : worker=1 PID:8 timeout (16s > 15s), killing
[2014-10-27T21:13:31.731646 #14]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
[2014-10-27T21:13:31.694690 #2] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 8 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=1
at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET
```

I'm just using the free version of heroku, I want to make sure it works before upgrading but is that my only option at this point?

Also I am able to run this locally perfectly fine using either `rails server` or `foreman start`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku docs say [this about H13](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h13-connection-closed-without-response):

> ## H13 - Connection closed without response
>
> This error is thrown when a process in your web dyno accepts a connection, but then closes the socket without writing anything to it.
>
> One example where this might happen is when a Unicorn web server is configured with a timeout shorter than 30s and a request has not been processed by a worker before the timeout happens. In this case, Unicorn closes the connection before any data is written, resulting in an H13.

A couple lines up, you have an error about a process timing out after 15s:

```
ERROR -- : worker=1 PID:8 timeout (16s > 15s), killing
```

Heroku help has a section on [timeout settings](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout#timeout-behavior):

> Depending on your language you may be able to set a timeout on the app server level. One example is Ruby’s Unicorn. In Unicorn you can set a timeout in `config/unicorn.rb` like this:
>
> `timeout 15`
>
> The timer will begin once Unicorn starts processing the request, if 15 seconds pass, then the master process will send a SIGKILL to the worker but no exception will be raised.

That matches the error messages in your log. I'd look into it.

Comment: I do have a line in config/unicorn.rb that says `timeout 15` and at one point I did change it to `timeout 30` to no avail

Comment: I'm just going to accept this as the answer because it seems to be working now consistently so I'm not sure what was causing this issue.

Comment: Eli, Any change in this situation?  I occasionally get this error, but seems to go away just about the time I start troubleshooting.  I seems like it is most likely to happen after the app sits idle for a day or so, almost like it is partially asleep.

Comment: @SteveO7 it's not happening as much as before but it still will happen maybe once or twice a day.

Comment: the timeout actually has to be less than 30 (e.g. 29)